# Reprogram AT32F403 Hoverboard with ST-Link

Tags: st-link

I'm trying to reprogram my Hoverboard in order to build some projects. It has a board which uses an AT32F403 chip.

I'm using the info of https://github.com/cloidnerux/hoverboard-firmware-hack and a virtual machine with Ubuntu in order to perform this procedure; Linux seems simpler to approach that than other solutions.

Also, I'm using OpenOCD to recognize the board, but after I installed the STLink utility I get the message below.

Has anyone already performed this procedure? Any solutions?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any actual ST-Link hardware plugged in?

Comment: This means that the st-link V2 hardware device is not plugged in or can't be found on USB. Do you not have access to a windows machine with the st-link utility software?

Comment: yes, I have st-link v2 hardware plugged in. I also have a windows machine with st-link utility but got an error (I think because the board has at32f403 chip). I read that the simpler alternatives when you have a board with at32f403 chip is using linux.

Answer (score 1):

On VirtualBox, you need to actually [link the USB port to the virtual machine](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-enable-usb-in-virtualbox/).

There is an option to do so, once done, on linux you can then list the usb devices with `lsusb` to make sure the system detects it.

Make sure, if any driver are required, that they are installed.

STLink works just fine on windows, doing all this in a VM might be more trouble than just doing it in your original system, especially handling the usb. You can compile on the VM, then take the binary and flash it from windows with the ST utilities.

Comment: Already tested it and seems that is not recognizing it with command lsusb, I read on the article below that one way is to make it throught openocd because the board has a at32f403 chip and it's not native of stm32 utility software.
 I also edited the  src/flash/nor/stm32f1x.c with the code below which is one of the steps .
anyone can help identify what are the steps needed?
code:
case 0x242: /* AT32F403 */
    page_size = 2048;
    stm32x_info->ppage_size = 2;
    max_flash_size_in_kb = 512;
    break;
--------

full steps
https://github.com/cloidnerux/hoverboard-firmware-hack

Comment: Your problem is most likely the VM itself not taking the USB ports.